# Excel Formula - How to allocate pallets to trucks

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a list of pallets in excel with the pallet number, and the temp type (Dry / Chilled / Frozen).

Each truck type (Dry / Chill / Frozen Truck) can carry different amounts of pallets:

- Dry truck = 20 pallets
- Chill Truck = 19 pallets
- Frozen Truck = 18 pallets

I now need to allocate "truck number" to each pallet.  The truck number is just a chronological number (IE. Dry1, Dry2, Dry3...).  So for example, the first 20 Dry pallets in the list will be allocated in "DryTruck1".  The next 20 pallets will be allocated in "DryTruck2" etc.

I cant think of the formula to do this.  I've created my own counters for the pallets.  So i have a column on each line displaying "DryPallet1", "DryPallet2" etc.  But i don't know the best way to somehow use this to allocate each pallet to a truck based on the capacity of the truck.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Added pic of problem to visualize easier:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bp2g.jpg

Comment: A screen print of you excel with sample data could be of more help as well

Comment: Now added screenshot

Comment: By the way, i cant do an IF statement (if between x and y, then 1...) because this could potentially be thousands of pallets.  My IF statement would be huge!!

Comment: Maybe Excel isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: @duffymo Why not? This doesn't surpass Excel capabilities in any way, it doesn't even need VBA

Comment: The accepted answer says you're right.  I was leaping to the assumption that this was an optimization problem of some kind, with constraints to be satisfied.  It's far simpler than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below formula, t worked perfectly as expected
 `=CONCATENATE(C8,"Truck",IF(D8/IF(C8="Chill",$C$3,IF(C8="Dry",$C$2,IF(C8="Frozen",$C$4,0)))<1,1,ROUNDUP(D8/IF(C8="Chill",$C$3,IF(C8="Dry",$C$2,IF(C8="Frozen",$C$4,0))),0)))`

[image]